# Prevent re render of shared ListHeaderComponent

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a social media app where i have a container component that has the following structure

```
<MyContainer>
   <SelectionBar/>
   {condition? <FlatListA header={header}/> : <FlatListB header={header}/>}
<MyContainer/>
```

the selection bar has buttons that determine which FlatList to display for the purpose of this question lets say messages FlatList vs posts FlatList

these two FlatLists have different listeners and data so they need to be their own component but they share the same ListHeaderComponent which is a feature similar to snapchat stories

the problem is when the user switches between two FlatLists the stories flicker because the component is re rendered because its two different FlatLists

the header needs to be inside the flatlist as a ListHeaderComponent because when the user scrolls down the stories should not stick to the top

**is there any way to prevent this re rendering?**

I've tried React.memo but that did not work

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent re-rendering of same component by using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

You can define your `header` component and pass it as a prop like:

```
import { memo } from "react";
import FlatListA from "./FlatListA";
import FlatListB from "./FlatListB";

const header = memo((props) => {
  console.log("header render");
  return <h1>this is header</h1>;
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FlatListA header={header} />
      <FlatListB header={header} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and you can use it in your `FlatList` components like:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function FlatListA(props) {
  console.log("flatlista render");

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <props.header />
      FlatlistA {toggle}
      <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>toogle state</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can take a look at this example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-usage-t2fp9) and click buttons to change state and see console outputs that it does not re-render header components.